# errors thrown while installing graphql-yoga on ubuntu

Tags: graphql, mern

[Errors after installing GraphQL Yoga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7fpr.png)

I tried to follow this tutorial video by Edureka https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpJO0T08Bnc and used alternative instructions for install on Ubuntu. Things have gone terribly wrong, because I cannot access the app on localhost:4000.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the server? Let follow me.

1. `yarn add graphql-yoga` or `npm install graphql-yoga --save`
2. create the '.babelrc' then write into `{
   "presets": [ "env", "stage-3" ]
   }`
3. yarn add global babel-cli, yarn add babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-state-3
   Cuz intall these, if you want to es6. you can install this.
4. `create the index.js` and add this

   ```
   `import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';
    import resolvers from './graphql/resolvers'

     const server = new GraphQLServer({
         typeDefs: "./graphql/schema.graphql",
         resolvers: resolvers
   }); 

   server.start(() => console.log("Graphql Server Running "));`
   ```
5. This is my package.json. Follow this "script"

   `{
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "main": "index.js",
     "license": "MIT",
     "dependencies": {
       "graphql-yoga": "^1.16.7"
    },
     "scripts": {
      "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"
    },
     "devDependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
     "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
     "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1"
    }
   }`
6. Make the schema.graphql, resolvers.js

These are my "Initail create GraphQL Yoga Setting"

Comment: It's not a server. It's a desktop Ubuntu machine that I am trying to set up the development environment on.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could help me via remote control.